# What is the difference between мои зовут and меня зовут?

Tags: словоупотребление

When saying what my name is, which one should I use and why?

Answer (score 7):

You should use `меня зовут`.

Literal translation:

`меня зовут` -> `they call me`

`мои зовут` -> `my [who?] call` - doesn't make sense here

Answer (score 4):

There are some exceptions, but, as a rule, in absence of prepositions, when you translate "X foobars Y with Z", X is in nominative, Y is in accusative, Z is in instrumental.

In "they call me", "me" is Y, so you need accusative of "я", which is "меня".

"мои" is plural of "my" or "mine" and I don't understand why you think it applies here.

Answer (score 2):

you should use `Меня зовут` when you are introducing yourself.

```
привет, меня зовут Аарон
```

Because меня зовут is the most common word that Russian recognize when they introducing themselves, even to foreigner who know Russian.

Answer (score 1):

`Меня зовут` is directly translated like `my name is`. I.e. `меня зовут Петр` -> `my name is Peter`. In most cases you should use this construction.

`Мои зовут` is not a common and grammatically correct construction in Russian language. It can be used as a slang phrase like `my [friends] are calling me`. Cant find a proper example in English.

P.S. Of course there are so many cases where you can hear these phrases in a different meanings, but these two are the most common and correct IMO.

Comment: `Мои зовут` is quite correct in Russian: omission is a commonplace thing. For example: `У нас с Васей совсем непохожие родители. Мои † зовут меня дома по-просту Петькой, а Васины † его ‡ — сухо, Василием.` Here, † and ‡ denote the omissions of `родители` и `зовут`. In some cases, `мои`, `твои`, `наши`, `ваши` can be used with no defined word without verbal context at all. It then typically (but not always) means kin, family, friends. `Здорово, как там твои?` — Hello, how's your family doing?